# How to optimise multi table join view for a faster response?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, optimization, bigdata

**Problem Statement**

I have a page where it has to show records from a **multi join query** (view made up of multiple joins on different tables and sub views). Two of the six tables that are being joined are **growing in size very rapidly** over time, in the process the query is becoming **slower and slower**.

I have **no authority to redesign** the schema and I am supposed to use the existing tables and **show summary** of the data available. Users are given an options to filter master data over multiple column values and ranges so for every filter/unfilter action, I hit the repository.

**What have I tried?**

- I have optimised tables already with indexes where ever it is possible.
- I have moved to a higher memory and cpu power computer for the mysql server

**Technologies being used**
Coming to implementation, its MySQL DB, with SpringJPA+Hibernate on top of it. Two of the tables have over million records and currently the repository query takes 20 seconds of time which is unacceptable.

Any hints on **how can this be optimised** like in memory caches/databases to use or try? I appreciate any pointers in the right direction!

Comment: And how does the join look?

Comment: So we need to magically know the structure, queries etc. No problem. Just do the following read [mcve] and you will find the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "summary of the data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ram,

As we don't have access to your current query or, at least, the expected output you should try to:

1. Cache data as much as you can. You can you strategies such as:

   1.1. Create an intermediate table to store the global data in order to make things fast to search
   1.2 Cache the queries data used and associate it with a condition hash. Take a look at Redis, he is pretty fast an can store a lot of information each time;
2. Don't do you all the joins if you don't need them in your search;
3. Try, if possible, to implement lazy loading (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) in your query.
4. Split your output. For example, if you have month data, cache data for each closed month so you can focus your query just on the recent data
5. Split your output in small steps. If you can break your query into smaller subsets and present each subset individually, make use of Ajax so the user could see that his data is already appearing.

I have a start screen that use to take 2 minutes to appear due to the large amount of statistics we show. So we split it into smaller pages (using 4 and 5) and made intensive use of cache (1.2). Now it loads in 1s (it takes time to render the charts).

Good luck

Comment: Nice answer I will try in my current problem, already upvoted for your effort.